# Getting results with association that belongs only to a certain list of categories

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two small tables like this:

Users:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Mike  |
|  3 | Smith |
|  4 | Kurt  |
|  5 | Tim   |
+----+-------+
```

Resources:

```
+----+------------+-------+---------+
| id |    name    | type  | user_id |
+----+------------+-------+---------+
|  1 | sunset     | text  |       1 |
|  2 | sunrise    | image |       2 |
|  3 | moon       | image |       1 |
|  4 | earth      | sound |       3 |
|  5 | clouds     | sound |       2 |
|  6 | tree       | image |       4 |
|  7 | flower     | text  |       4 |
|  8 | water      | text  |       4 |
|  9 | wind       | text  |       1 |
| 10 | animal     | image |       1 |
| 11 | open_door  | sound |       5 |
| 12 | close_door | sound |       5 |
+----+------------+-------+---------+
```

Given this, we can see that

John owns resources of type text and image
Mike owns resources of type image and sound 
Smith owns resources of type sound
Kurt owns text and images
Tim owns only sounds

The problem is: I want to retrieve the users that owns exclusively text and/or images, if the user owns any other type of resource that is not text or images, the user should not be fetched in the result set.

Is there any way to accomplish this with criteria or HQL?

Currently, my query is returning users that own text or images, but they also own other type of resources:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Mike  |
|  4 | Kurt  |
|  5 | Tim   |
+----+-------+
```

The result set should only show John and Kurt, since they are the only ones that own text and/or images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your user domain class looks something like

```
class User {
   String name
}
```

and the resource class looks something like

```
class Resource {
   String name
   String type
   User user
}
```

then you can use this HQL:

```
User.executeQuery("""
   select distinct r.user from Resource r
   where (r.type='image' or r.type='text')
     and r.user not in (
         select distinct r.user from Resource r where r.type<>'image' and r.type<>'text'
     )""")
```

Comment: That is exactly how I did it!
But I'm kinda worried about the nested query's efficiency, I'm expectig the Resources table table to grow to 100000 rows or more, I'm gonna test it with a big table. Thanks.